# Android 8 confirmation before restart

Tags: reboot, 8.1-oreo

Is it possible to configure Android 8 to ask for confirmation before powerdown/restart? Is that option manufacturer dependant?

Comment: isn't the selection screen for shutdown/reboot itself already confirmation dialog enough for you? just tap on *back* (or any area outside the popup) and the dialog dissappeares

Answer (score 1):

- Android does not offer this feature by itself (barring restart confirmation after applying system update).
- It is possible that OEM customized ROMs or custom ROMs provide this feature. If you're device is rooted, it is possible - one way I am aware of is using GravityBox Xposed module